# How can I permanently connect a portable dishwasher to the water and drain lines under my sink?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

Because our kitchen is small and our counter depths are not a standard size we have to resort to this tiny countertop dishwasher which is meant to be attached to the faucet but we want it attached permanently. I'm trying to find the best (no leak) way of attaching this up to the waterline and waste pipe near the sink. Any thoughts, could I use the connection that came with it and just cut the hose and add on new connectors that fit the water line and drain connection (dishwasher connection)?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would be concerned that maybe the dishwasher isn't designed to have constant pressure on the intake line.

Answer (score 4):

Best thing to do is first go back to the manufacturer to see if they have instructions for a permanent water supply installation. That will let you know if the model you have can handle constant water pressure on the supply side. If so, follow their instructions. If you're comfortable doing basic under counter plumbing it should be a fairly simple installation.
It will require adding an inline on/off valve to your hot water supply under the sink. I'd recommend a 1/4 turn ball valve for quick on and off. I would not use the supply line shown in your picture. I would purchase a new supply line with the proper metal fittings from your home store or plumbing store. The drain line can be hooked up like any dishwasher into the disposal, if you have one, or by tapping into the drain line under the sink with a proper fitting at a point above the P trap. If the DW is on the countertop above the drain connection you will not have to be concerned about installing a high loop on the drain line.

[image]

If the manufacturer doesn't recommend a permanent installation with constant internal water pressure you could consider placing the quarter turn shutoff valve in a spot convenient to turning it on only when the dishwasher is in use. **This will require remembering to turn it off after every use or risk water damage.**

Comment: Remembering to turn off after each use is the problem.  Probably one of the few things you want a smart thing for.

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION:

I called the manufacturer there is nothing they will send.

Instead simply buy a cheap single line faucet and hook it up to the water line.

For the drainage, cut it off at the end and shove it into the receptacle on your garbage disposal. I used glue to create the perfect seal (remember the sewage is not pressurized)

Comment: What's a "single line facet"?

Comment: While possibly valid, it is not clear what you are proposing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel A faucet with only one incoming water supply line connection.